# Move all files into another location in a Swift script

Tags: ios, swift, bash, scripting, nsfilemanager

To start, I am a total noob at Swift.

I am trying to move files from one location to another in Swift. For example, I have a function which lets me use bash commands within my Swift script. I simply had the following to move all files from one folder into current location:  `shell("mv \(currentDirectory)/archive/*.crash \(currentDirectory)")`.

However I was told to use the fileManager API to move files and by using filemanager I could have have better error reporting capability. I did see that Apple has the following command: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1414750-moveitem
EDIT**: So I have been able to figure out how to do this with the following code:

```
let files = try? fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: "\(currentDirectory)/archive")
    if let files = files {
        for file in files {
            do {
                try fileManager.moveItem(atPath: "\(currentDirectory)/archive/\(file)",
                toPath:"\(currentDirectory)/ips/\(file)")
                print(files.count)
            } catch {
                print("Error \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run my script, it moves the files as expected but now it is crashing my script with a Fatal error: Index out of range

See screenshot below:
[image: error]

Does anyone know if this is due to the contentOfDirectory throwing an empty array?

Comment: Replace `print("issue moving files")` with `print(error)` so that if there _is_ an error you find out what it is. Also, use URLs, not paths. Plus, I would not recommend using `shell` to unzip the files.

Comment: What would you suggest to unzip files instead?

Comment: Try searching on "swift unzip".

Comment: Ok so I figured out how to move multiple files from one directory to another but now I am getting a "Fatal error: Index out of range"

Comment: I really really really must recommend you stop using file paths. What you are doing is not a good way to refer to files or directories. Use file URLs. As for the index out of range, I don't see the code where an index is used.

Comment: Hello matt- thank you for your message. This is the code I am currently using: `let files = try? fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: "\(currentDirectory)/archive")
    if let files = files {
        for file in files {
            do {
                try fileManager.moveItem(atPath: "\(currentDirectory)/archive/\(file)",
                toPath:"\(currentDirectory)/ips/\(file)")
                print(files.count)
            } catch {
                print("Error \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}`

Comment: How would I be able to convert the file paths to URL?

Comment: I was able to use the example code from the comments to copy my files.